# Show/hide 2 divs with 3 different contents in cycle

Tags: jquery

Hi I have problem with Jquery when I need make this script:

I have 2 divs in websites and I must change their contents in cycle. I have 3 different contents.

Planned functionality:
1. 1st content show in left div
2. hide last show conent and show 2nd content in right div
3. hide last show conent and show 3rd content in left div
4. hide last show conent and show 1st content in right div
5. hide last show conent and show 2nd content in left div
6. hide last show conent and show 3rd content in right div
And these still in cycle, logically with some delay. In one time i need visible only 1 content.

Because I need fadin/fadeout effect then I need JQuery, not only JS.
My various attempts have failed and it's not worth it to show.

Can someone help me?

Comment: post something that you have done .. atleast the HTML so that we don't have to work on HTML again...without it i am sure user here, wil spent not more that 4 secs of there time

Comment: My last try was make it without "for" or some another type of cycle, for test. http://jsfiddle.net/UDFZs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fadeOut` and `fadeIn` both accept callback functions that will fire once the animation is completed. You can use them to fire your animations in a cyclic manner.

```
function cycle() {
    // determine current and next element
    current.fadeOut(function() {
        next.fadeIn(cycle);
    });
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5qKJL/)

The current state could also be inherent in the order array, which may be neater than the solution with an `index` variable above.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rCSMN/)

Comment: It seems that this is exactly what I want. When it is time to give it a try and if everything is in order and give a upvote and accept this answer. Thanks for it.

Comment: So it works thanks again. I only add some delay. I upvote your answer and accept it.